# Making an MSSQL Driven Calendar in .NET c#

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, calendar

I'm new to .NET and my first project is to create a event calendar to be populated from a events table in mSQL. I know there is a calendar object in the standard components but wondered if i'm better off populating a table view manually as i didn't know if there were lots of limitations to the standard object/component.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Unless this is a school assignment, it may be easier for you to try something a little less complicated to get accustomed to the .NET environment. That's just a suggestion, though.

Comment: Unfortunately this is for work so i've got no choice but at least it will keep me busy :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done quite easily with the built-in calendar control that .NET provides. You're basically dealing with the `DayRender` event.

An excellent example can be found here: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/munnamax/DatabaseDriven08212007012112AM/DatabaseDriven.aspx

Comment: thank you, appreciate the link. Once i've finished the full working system i'll put a link to a project file to help others

Answer (score 1):

You can use the standard calendar control. It will give you the ability to perform code in each cell (day) creation, so you can query your DB, find your dates, and during that paticular date's load, you can write any necessary content inside the cell.